# I am trying to use mailto: to get reply on my mails but through <map>. It works perfect on <a> but don't know why it doesn't work on <map>

Tags: html, css

If you want to try it out send a mail to yourself using below blocks, the first one() works perfectly but in  it opens in another tab.

```
    <a href="mailto:contact@mydomain.com?subject=Heloo&body=I&nbsp;Just&nbsp;Clicked&nbsp;Here!!" style='text-decoration:none; color:#ff0000; font: 20px "Tahoma";text-align: center;font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;' ><h1>Example Text</h1></a></b> 


    <h3><img src="https://image.ibb.co/djXDma/index.png"   alt="Test" style='cursor:pointer;' usemap="#redirection" ></a>
    <map name="redirection">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10100,11000" alt="redirection" href="mailto:contact@mydomain.com?subject=Heloo&body=I&nbsp;Just&nbsp;Clicked&nbsp;Here!!">
    </map>
```

[I want this output both the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7lGd.jpg)

Comment: What doesn't work?  Do you get an error message, does nothing happen, what?

Comment: Using the <a tag I get a new composed mail  with the body and subject that I desire but when map is used it asks me to select an app to open the link.

Comment: What browser are you using? I just tried the latest versions of firefox and chrome and both behave the same when clicking on the image and the text. They open the associated email app.

Comment: Yeah, they both open the associated email app, but when inside email <a composes mail directly through current mail , but map still asks for email app but it should directly compose mail as it is already inside mail.